# using git merge judiciously

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

Let us say me and my colleague are working on two features(or enhancements), so we create our own feature branches from a common base branch. When we are done, we open pull requests for the team to review the changes and merge it back into base branch. Naturally there will be more than one pull request open. If one of the pull requests gets merged first, I thought the other developers have to update their pull requests with the latest commits from base branch (i.e. update his local base branch, merge it to local feature branch, push to remote feature branch). I usually use `git merge` to achieve this.

I would like to whether I am using `git merge` correctly or not. Is updating the local feature branches with latest from base all the time really needed or I am doing some unnecessary work by polluting the git history with those merge commits? What if there are other commits to the base branch while we were developing our feature branches?

Answer (score 1):

> Is updating the local feature branches with latest from base all the time really needed?

Sometimes. It's necessary anytime there are conflicts merging your feature branch into the base; in that case you must update your feature branch with the base branch to resolve those conflicts. Outside of that, it's a good idea to keep it up to date in case there are new changes that would affect your branch, or simply so you can test what the latest code will be like after the merge, but again it isn't *required* in this case.

> or I am doing some unnecessary work by polluting the git history with those merge commits?

An alternative to merging in the base branch, is rebasing your feature branch onto the latest base branch. This will avoid creating those merge commits. The end result *state* is the same regardless of whether you use merge or rebase, but the graph will have less merge commits with rebase. Which way to go is mostly personal preference, but a good rule of thumb is that it's OK to rebase personal feature branches that aren't shared, but you don't want to rebase shared branches such as the base branch. Note if you rebase a personal feature branch that you already pushed, you'll need to force push it the next time.

Comment: I understand the option of `git rebase`. But I am still an amateur rebaser. So I would refrain from doing it.

Comment: @MadhuReddy Sure- have merge commits until you get more comfortable with rebase. The merge commits aren't hurting anything; some people actually prefer having them over using rebase. By the way, I understand that rebase is a little intimidating at first. It's easier once you understand it well enough that you know exactly what it will do before you do it. Then your confidence will increase since you'll know if it worked. And, in Git, **once you commit**, you can always go back to the state you were in before you started. This makes it fairly low risk to play around and learn commands.